# How to know I had network intrusion and system tampering?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a small home business and all of the sudden, my machine could not login anymore. I have  some weird "Login failed".

I managed to login with another user. When I got in, my C: drive, a lot of files were erased, and my external HD was wiped out. Can windows do this by it's own? Has anyone gotten something like that? I had issues with an employee and I'm wondering if he could have gotten in somehow and erased data.

Comment: Does it seem random or is there a pattern to what is gone? For example, does it look like files from all over the drive have been erased or more like a systematic erasure resulting in the last folder accessed being partially emptied? Have you considered a virus? Did you examine the normal user account to see if the password was changed or if the profile has simply become corrupt?

Comment: The profile seem corrupted, and I only have a "normal user". Did not want to do a system restore since I don't want to loose info that might point to a hacking of my machine.

Comment: I might need to run a tool to detect opened ports for backdoors, do you know any?

Comment: You said you logged in with a different account. So the one you normally log in with is corrupt? How can you tell? Is the wallpaper wrong? are the autoruns different? are Start Menu, etc. settings different? Which version of Windows are you using? For XP, I use [WWDC](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Firewall/Windows-Worms-Doors-Cleaner.shtml) to check if Windows is hardened or not. For Windows 7, the usual tools like [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) and [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) can show you open ports.

Comment: Windows 7. C: drive had some folder and they are not there anymore. This seems to strange to be windows suddenly deciding to erase some folders that contained sensitive data.

Comment: Were they desktop items or start menu items? Many malware utilities will hide all desktop icons or start menu icons. The files may still be available, just hidden.

Comment: all hidden files are shown, I strongly believe the user had left a backdoor and he got in and deleted a bunch of files. But don't want to fall into paranoia!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely! Anyone with sufficiently elevated account privileges and access can do quite a bit of damage. And they don't even have to be there to do it either. So, yes. It sounds like your ex-disgruntled-employee may have done exactly that - or a virus/worm did it. It's not likely that Windows did anything unless some hardware was failing or some other major screw-up had occurred. Otherwise, this is not normal.

So as far as your ex-employee goes, if his account or whatever account he used had the rights to modify certain files - which can include a complete drives - then it's very likely he might have had a field day. If he had access to your LAN then he may have done it through a WiFi connection too - probably from the parking lot or somewhere close. But if your system is connected to the Internet, and even if firewalls are working, he still could have done it from almost anywhere on planet earth. It's hard to say since I (we) don't know how you have your computer(s) configured.

This would also be a good example of why you should be changing passwords. Not just for individual user accounts but also for WiFi connections and maybe even certain encrypted files. Any time an employee leaves their job this should be standard operating procedure either before they get their walking papers or within minutes afterwords. At the very least, any user accounts this person may have had access to needs to be reduced to guest privileges and then maybe even be deleted.

You may even want to consider specific user privileges for anyone else too. It is possible to give people access to files in a central location but not allow them to change or delete anything. Anyone having such access would then have to copy files to their own PC or their own elevated privileges directory in order to have the ability to change or delete anything. Then again, you could just let someone have their own folder on a central location where you - the administrator - would also be able to make nightly backups to another location that only you have access to (hint hint).

Then again, as I said, this may have been the result of a virus or worm - or even a security vulnerability from a lack of updates. Obviously, that would be a huge reason to stay on top of those annoying updates too. And not just Microsoft's updates either - all updates! In fact, there's some pretty major concerns with Adobe Flash and Reader products right now since even Adobe has reported "security holes" in both products "where a malicious user/processes might be allowed access to the system" if the product(s) is not updated. Oracles Java is another huge thing to keep on top of and for much the same reasons too. In fact, if you have any Java 6 or earlier versions installed you are strongly encouraged by Oracle to uninstall them and install version 7 - this is NOT an automatic update they can make happen either.

So not staying on top of the updates is most likely the culprit if you haven't done it lately. I know this can be a huge time vampire and a major PITA for some people. But if you have a LAN and/or access to the Internet then it's pretty much a requirement in order to stay as safe from these kind of incidents (and others) as possible. Not doing it just makes it that much easier for disgruntled employees (and other malicious individuals) to get in and cause havoc too.

I don't know if that helps, but at least you have some things to think about.